# Nonlinear stability question

Tags: stability, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I am looking for a simple example where a system is linearly unstable, but nonlinearly unstable or stable, depending on the sign of the initial perturbation.

For instance, assume the linear normal mode perturbation to some system goes like $a_0 e^{\lambda t}$ for $a_0$ a constant and $\lambda>0$ and real. If I then numerically integrate this and find that the full nonlinear behavior depends on the sign of $a_0$, how do I proceed in the nonlinear stability analysis? For instance, do I then assume $a_0 = \epsilon a_0(\epsilon t)$, for $\epsilon$ small and develop an equation for $a_0(\epsilon t)$ up to some asymptotic order $O(\epsilon^n)$, $n>2$, in the full nonlinear equations? I can't seem to find a canonical way to proceed.

Comment: Nick it depends on the system.  Are you looking at some type of water wave or atmospheric wave?  What is the free energy source?

Comment: I thought that the nonlinear stability of a system was the same as the linear stability of the system, according to the Hartman-Grobman theorem.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I would love to have a simple closed system like some kind of nonlinear oscillator. The end goal is related to a problem in water waves.

Comment: @probably_someone - Nope.  I know of at least two systems in plasmas where they are linearly stable but nonlinearly unstable.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Which systems are those? I want to look them up.

Comment: @probably_someone - One relates to non-resonant instabilities where the linear stage is skipped (i.e., growth rate immediately depends upon amplitude rather than starting as a constant as it would be in a linear system).  The second relates to BGK phase space holes, whereby the plasma is stable but the holes grow in amplitude by mediating the exchange energy/momentum between different plasma species (e.g., hot and cold electrons).

Comment: @NickP - I think you have a typo in the first fragment of the first sentence.  Don't you mean to say "...system is linearly stable, but nonlinearly unstable..."?

Comment: @honeste_vivere No, the question is as intended. I will add some more details this afternoon.

Comment: For finite-dimensional systems, linear and non-linear stability are indeed the same thing. For *infinite-dimensional* systems they are not. I am not aware of any systematic perturbational method which would be fail-proof in such cases. The proofs of non-linear (in)stability I have seen used indirect functional methods or explicit analytical solutions rather than perturbational analysis.

Comment: @Void - I think the point in many nonlinear instability systems is that perturbations do not work because you cannot separate _static_ and _fluctuating_ terms like you do when linearizing the relevant equations.  There are some systems where perturbations never work (I think QCD is one of those cases, but it's been >10 years since my last quantum class).

Comment: @honeste_vivere Well, from a more mathematical perspective, I saw it rather as a problem of a norm - the measure of stability is necessarily functional, nonlocal, and it *does* matter which norm you choose to assess the stability. You may choose a norm with respect to which the very same problem is either linearly stable or unstable - this will never happen in finite dimension.

Comment: @NickP - Okay, I think I understand your question now.  Have you tried looking at quasi-linear theory and the basic approach there?  I think Void was indirectly eluding to something like this in one of his previous comments.